# Why can't I authenticate to Google Finance via ClientLogin by jQuery AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-finance

I can't seem to authenticate by making a POST request via ajax! I always get an HTTP 400 error. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Cross Site Scripting, dummy! You can't do that with vanilla JavaScript.

If you really need to use JavaScript, [a client library is available](http://code.google.com/apis/finance/developers_guide_js.html).